# Selecting Pandas Dataframe satisfying membership

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data `df` looks like

```
Label1 Label2
a      {l1,l2}
b      {l1}
c      {}
d      {l3}
e      {l3,l2}
```

I want to be able to select rows whose Label2 column contains `l2`, i.e., rows with `label1 =a and e`.   I know about the `isin` method, e.g., `df['Label2'].isin(..)`,  but this is not the same kind of membership question (more like the inverse). I want something that looks like `df['Label2'].contains('l2')`.

Comment: is "l2" a string?

Comment: are values in `Label2` actually sets? or is that  a string?

Comment: Also, could you post a desired output, so it is easier to help you

Comment: @coldspeed,  in my example it's a string, but doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a series of `sets`, just use the *intersection* operator `&`

```
df.loc[df['Label2'] & {'l2'}]
```

Comment: Thanks, using intersection achieves this (and also looks like an efficient way)

Comment: how is using `df.loc[]` different than just using `df[..]`1

Comment: @VuNguyen For this purpose, not different at all ;}

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "l2" is a string, and "Label2" is made up of sets, a simple solution would just be to convert the set column to string and perform an `str.contains`:

```
label = "l2"
df[df['Label2'].astype(str).str.contains(r'\b{}\b'.format(label))]

  Label1    Label2
0      a  {l1, l2}
4      e  {l2, l3}
```

---

Another option is a list comprehension:

```
df[['l2' in x if isinstance(x, set) else False for x in df['Label2']]]

  Label1    Label2
0      a  {l1, l2}
4      e  {l2, l3}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `isin` with `any` after convert the `sets` `columns` to df

```
df[pd.DataFrame(df.Label2.tolist()).isin(['l2']).any(1)]
```